# Making list of posts with chosen description

Tags: php, wp-query, loop

I wanna do list of my properties with my chosen data.

I made my own code, but it doesnt show all list of my properties (I have 400 properites)

http://testimo1.smarthost.pl/wordpress/klienci

```
    <?php $my_Property = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'property'
    )); ?>
    <?php while($my_Property->have_posts()) : $my_Property->the_post(); ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="Lista">
        <h4><?php the_title(''); ?></h4>
        <div class="thumbnail lista"
        <p class="klientFirma">Firma: <?php the_field('Property_ID'); ?></p>
        <p> <?php the_taxonomies( '' ) ?> </p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Whats wrong?
Plese help

Comment: Have you closed your while loop I see the endwhile missing

Comment: Its OK, i solved the problem